# Python concurrent.futures ProcessPoolExecutor for creating multiple .json-files

Tags: python, json, list, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I have a problem with creating .json-files through a function and also multiprocessing it via the concurrent.futures module in Python.

My code looks like this:

```py
import json, concurrent.futures

iterable_list = [string1, string2, string3, string4, ...]

def lovely_function(arg):
    with open(string1+'.json', 'w') as write_file:
        print('opening',string1,'.json file.')            

        ...loop through stuff and create a dictionary...

        print('closing',string1,'.json file.')
        json.dump(dictionary,write_file)

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.map(lovely_function, iterable_list)
```

When I run the script in my console (Ubuntu 16.something) it will print the "opening .json"-part for every item in my iterable_list but it will only print one "closing .json". However, all the .json-files are created and dumped into my target folder but only one (the one with the closing statement) of them contains data. Sometimes I get no "closing .json" at all.

I have double-checked my function and it is working properly if you feed it manually (e.g. *lovely_function(string1)*)

What am I doing wrong? Any hints or tips?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I might need to add that I work with Django Queries in the main part of the function. I'm not sure if this makes things more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Django ORM (which is part of my data shuffling within the function) won't really work well together with multiprocessing in any way. If you look at different posts it's always about sharing/opening connections. I'll have a further look.